# Which gcc version introduced `-fstack-protector-strong`?

Tags: bash, gcc

In my build script, I want to conditionally add `-fstack-protector-strong` to my `CFLAGS` if the gcc supports it (my project builds using multiple versions of gcc).

I want my build script (written in bash) to parse the output of `gcc --version` and automatically add this flag if the gcc supports it.

Which version of gcc is the earliest to include the `-fstack-protector-strong` flag?

Comment: There are many online compilers that supports a lot of different gcc version... just try it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking inspiration from @KamilCuk's answer but bashifying it:

```
    add_supported_cc_flag() {
        CC=$1
        CFLAG_TO_CHECK=$2
        C_FILE=/tmp/test.$$.c
        O_FILE=${C_FILE/.c/.o}
        rm -f ${C_FILE}
        cat > ${C_FILE} <<EOF
        int main() { return 0; }
    EOF
        if $CC ${CFLAG_TO_CHECK} -c ${C_FILE} -o ${O_FILE} >/dev/null 2>&1
        then
             echo ${CFLAG_TO_CHECK}
        fi
        rm -f ${C_FILE} ${O_FILE}
    }

    CFLAGS="${CFLAGS} $(add_supported_cc_flag gcc -fstack-protector-strong)"
```

Answer (score 2):

> I want my build script (written in bash) to parse the output of gcc --version and automatically add this flag if the gcc supports it.

Instead of doing that, just call `gcc -fstack-protector-strong` with a valid source file and see if it compiles. Such method works universally for any compile option, which will save you time for searching which version has which options. You may take inspiration from CMake [check_c_compile_flag](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CheckCCompilerFlag.html) function.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that `-fstack-protector-strong` was first available in gcc 4.9.0.

The option doesn't show up in https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.5/gcc/Optimize-Options.html (4.8.5 was the last 4.8.x gcc version), but the option does show up in https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.0/gcc/Optimize-Options.html.

Note that `-fstack-protector-all` and `-fstack-protector` are available prior to gcc 4.9.0.